# tmux set-titles doesn't work?

Tags: tmux, xterm

To start `tmux` on every shell login, the following was added to the `~/.bashrc` (on the server):

```
if [ $TERM != "screen-256color" ] && [  $TERM != "screen" ]; then
    tmux attach || tmux new; exit
fi
```

I also want to change the window title to something like `user@server` (instead of `user@localhost`) when ssh into a host. Here's my `~/.tmux.conf`:

```
set -g prefix C-a
unbind C-b
bind C-a send-prefix

set -g set-titles on
set -g set-titles-string "#T"

bind-key o split-window -v
bind-key e split-window -h

bind-key w kill-pane

set -g terminal-overrides 'xterm*:smcup@:rmcup@'
```

As you can see, `set-titles` was set to `on`, but it doesn't work as expected.

More informations:

Outside of tmux:

```
$ echo $TERM
xterm
```

Inside of tmux:

```
$ echo $TERM
screen
```

`show -g`: https://clbin.com/h7oDh

`tmux info`: http://sprunge.us/XHCB

And here're the logs when running `tmux -vvvvv` for a bit:

- tmux-client-8441.log: https://clbin.com/eFwFF
- tmux-out-8443.log: https://clbin.com/MSKZv
- tmux-server-8443.log: https://clbin.com/JXwRN

If I comment out the lines in `~/.bashrc`, from my laptop, ssh to the server, the title bar shows correctly (`quanta@server`), then start `tmux` from there also works as expected.

But if I want to start `tmux` immediately after login, the title bar remains to be `quanta@Ubuntu` after ssh.

---

**UPDATE Fri May 10 07:51:23 ICT 2013**

I have deleted the `exit` command in order not to close the shell session when the last `tmux` window is closed:

```
if [ $TERM != "screen-256color" ] && [  $TERM != "screen" ]; then
    tmux attach || tmux new
fi
```

The strange thing is:

- ssh to server -> the title bar: `quanta@Ubuntu`
- detach from `tmux` -> the title bar switch to `quanta@server`
- attach to `tmux` again -> the title bar still shows correctly
  `quanta@server`

---

I'm not sure if it's related to the `PROMPT_COMMAND` environment variable or not:

Outside of `tmux`:

```
$ echo $PROMPT_COMMAND 
echo -ne "\033]0;${USER}@${HOSTNAME%%.*}:${PWD/#$HOME/~}"; echo -ne "\007"
```

Inside of `tmux`:

```
$ echo $PROMPT_COMMAND
echo -ne "\033_${USER}@${HOSTNAME%%.*}:${PWD/#$HOME/~}"; echo -ne "\033\\"
```

Comment: In case it isn't obvious in this question. His setup works fine, just not when he attempts to run it from his .bashrc.

Comment: Please provide the output from `tmux info`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Problem solved!

To enable native xterm mouse scrolling in `tmux`, a lot of [wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Tmux#Scrolling_issues), [Q & A site](https://superuser.com/a/326592/83649), [blog post](http://www.electricmonk.nl/log/2012/01/05/tmux-scrolling-with-shift-pageupdown/) suggest adding a line like:

```
set -g terminal-overrides 'xterm*:smcup@:rmcup@'
```

to `~/.tmux.conf`. And it is the culprit.

To allow xterm titles in terminal window, you also need to add the `XT` flag, something like this:

```
set -g terminal-overrides "xterm*:XT:smcup@:rmcup@"
```

Source: http://opennomad.com/content/goodbye-screen-hello-tmux

Comment: Thank for your post. In my case with `rxvt`, the setting is `set -ga terminal-overrides ",rxvt*:XT"`

Comment: As @favadi pointed out, the proper fix for this is to use the `-a` option with `set` to append the smcup/rmcup overrides. This will fix other weird issues, like not being able to set the cursor shape properly.

Answer (score 3):

Came across this thread from the tmux-users mailing list. The thread was titled: [set-titles not working](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.terminal-emulators.tmux.user/2245). There are a couple of things from this thread to try. There's a [cleaner version of the thread](http://www.mail-archive.com/tmux-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg02237.html) here as well.

#### XTerm Resources

For starters the eventual fix was to add the following line to your XTerm Resources file, `~/.Xresources`:

```
XTerm*allowSendEvents: true
```

#### Debugging tmux tips

There were also some debugging tips in this thread that may help you as well.

**verbose tmux**

1. close all tmux sessions
2. run the command: `tmux -vvvvv`
3. run the command: `vi foo`
4. save the file
5. exit tmux

After doing so you should have 3 files, something like these:

- tmux-out-21594.log
- tmux-client-21592.log
- tmux-server-21594.log

**tmux info**

```
$ tmux info
tmux 1.4, pid 22182, started Fri May 10 04:00:37 2013
socket path /var/run/tmux/tmux-500/default, debug level 0
system is Linux 2.6.35.14-106.fc14.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Nov 23 13:07:52 UTC 2011 x86_64
configuration file is /home/saml/.tmux.conf
protocol version is 6

Clients:
 0: /dev/pts/12 (8, 11): 0 [132x24 xterm] [flags=0x1/0x38, references=0]

Sessions: [5/10]
 0: 0: 1 windows (created Fri May 10 04:00:37 2013) [132x23] [flags=0x0]
   0: bash [132x23] [flags=0x8, references=1, last layout=-1]
     0: /dev/pts/48 22183 13 1/23, 135 bytes; UTF-8 0/23, 0 bytes

Terminals:
xterm [references=1, flags=0x0]:
 1: acsc: (string) ``aaffggiijjkkllmmnnooppqqrrssttuuvvwwxxyyzz{{||}}~~
 0: AX: (flag) true
 2: bel: (string) \007
 ...
 ...
144: smul: (string) \033[4m
145: vpa: (string) \033[%i%p1%dd
146: xenl: (flag) true

Jobs:
```

Comment: I already read that thread before asking here. `XTerm*allowSendEvents: true` didn't work. The log files has been uploaded. See my updated question.

Comment: In the future you should include these types of items in your question, so as to not waste everyone's time rehashing things you've already tried.